# Stack overflow in unmanaged IP - Xamarion iOS

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm just making a small app for iOS in Xamarin but in Visual Studio 2015 I keep getting this error when I run the application:

> critical: Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x2e8785, fault addr:
>   0xbff07ffc

Right some background to what I'm doing. I was programmatically adding UIControls into my main viewcontroller which was working just fine but the code was all over the place. So I decided to reorganize the mess into a new class which would display the uicontrols. But when I did all that and ran the application I then started getting that error.

Can anyone help me out or point me in the right direction?
If you need to see that code just let me know and I'll add it in.

Thanks.

*** UPDATED ***

**DrawMenu.cs**

```
namespace DrawingComponents
{
    class DrawMenu
    {
        UserInterfaceControls uicontrols;


        const int X_BTN = 100;
        const int Y_BTN = 100;
        const int PADDING = 5;

        float xMainPortrait; // Main views width
        float yMainPortrait; // Main views height

        float xSub; // Subviews width which is inrelation to the Mainviews dimensions.
        float ySub; // Subviews height which is inrelation to the Mainview demensions.

        float widthMainPortrait = 205;
        float heightMainPortrait = 310;

        public void PortraitNormal(UIView view)
        {
            xMainPortrait = ((float)view.Bounds.Size.Width - widthMainPortrait) / 2;
            yMainPortrait = ((float)view.Bounds.Size.Height - heightMainPortrait) / 2;

            // Draw the frame
            var mainFrame = new CGRect(xMainPortrait, yMainPortrait, widthMainPortrait, heightMainPortrait);
            uicontrols.mainview = new UIView(mainFrame);


            // Get the x and y coordinants of the mainview
            xSub = (float)uicontrols.mainview.Bounds.X;
            ySub = (float)uicontrols.mainview.Bounds.Y;

            // Get center of the mainview and last button
            float xCenter = ((float)uicontrols.mainview.Bounds.Size.Width / 2) - (X_BTN / 2);
            float yCenter = (Y_BTN * 2) + (PADDING * 2);

            // This will draw each component.
            uicontrols.btn_MySchedule.Frame = new CGRect(xSub, ySub, X_BTN, Y_BTN);
            uicontrols.btn_MyCareer.Frame = new CGRect(xSub + X_BTN + PADDING, ySub, X_BTN, Y_BTN);
            uicontrols.btn_MySocial.Frame = new CGRect(xSub, ySub + Y_BTN + PADDING, X_BTN, Y_BTN);
            uicontrols.btn_Feedback.Frame = new CGRect(xSub + X_BTN + PADDING, ySub + Y_BTN + PADDING, X_BTN, Y_BTN);
            uicontrols.btn_MyDetails.Frame = new CGRect(xCenter, yCenter, X_BTN, Y_BTN);


            uicontrols.mainview.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleMargins;

            uicontrols.btn_MySchedule.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;
            uicontrols.btn_MyCareer.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;
            uicontrols.btn_MySocial.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;
            uicontrols.btn_Feedback.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;
            uicontrols.btn_MyDetails.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;


            view.Add(uicontrols.mainview);

            uicontrols.mainview.AddSubview(uicontrols.btn_MySchedule);
            uicontrols.mainview.AddSubview(uicontrols.btn_MyCareer);
            uicontrols.mainview.AddSubview(uicontrols.btn_MySocial);
            uicontrols.mainview.AddSubview(uicontrols.btn_Feedback);
            uicontrols.mainview.AddSubview(uicontrols.btn_MyDetails);
        }

    }
}
```

**MainViewController.cs**

```
namespace DrawingComponents
{
    struct UserInterfaceControls
    {
        public UIView mainview;

        public UIButton btn_MySchedule;
        public UIButton btn_MyCareer;
        public UIButton btn_MySocial;
        public UIButton btn_Feedback;
        public UIButton btn_MyDetails;
    }


    class MainViewController : UIViewController
    {
        UserInterfaceControls uicontrols;
        DrawMenu menu = new DrawMenu();


        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {

            base.ViewDidLoad();


            // Instantiate menu buttons
            uicontrols.btn_MySchedule = new UIButton();
            uicontrols.btn_MyCareer = new UIButton();
            uicontrols.btn_MySocial = new UIButton();
            uicontrols.btn_Feedback = new UIButton();
            uicontrols.btn_MyDetails = new UIButton();

            // Set the image of each button
            uicontrols.btn_MySchedule.SetImage(UIImage.FromFile("images/myschedule.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
            uicontrols.btn_MyCareer.SetImage(UIImage.FromFile("images/mycareer.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
            uicontrols.btn_MySocial.SetImage(UIImage.FromFile("images/mysocial.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
            uicontrols.btn_Feedback.SetImage(UIImage.FromFile("images/feedback.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
            uicontrols.btn_MyDetails.SetImage(UIImage.FromFile("images/mydetails.png"), UIControlState.Normal);

            PositionControls(InterfaceOrientation);
        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            switch(toInterfaceOrientation)
            {
                case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
                case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
                case UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait:
                case UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }

        public override void WillAnimateRotation(UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation, double duration)
        {
            base.WillAnimateRotation(toInterfaceOrientation, duration);

            PositionControls(toInterfaceOrientation);
        }

        protected void PositionControls(UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            switch(toInterfaceOrientation)
            {
                case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
                case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
                    if (View.Bounds.Size.Width > 480)
                    {
                        // Add code here
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         // Add code here

                    }
                    break;
                case UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait:
                case UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
                    if (View.Bounds.Width > 414)
                    {
                        // Add code here
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        menu.PortraitNormal(View);
                    }
                break;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without any code, there is no way of knowing what the problem is.

Comment: If I may add, as a general practice you should always (if applicable) add your code when posting a Stack Overflow question - it's significantly easier to read through the code and spot the issues that to theoretically guess what could be causing the issue. Also, makes the people here generally more keen to respond - your question will look less like a homework assignment if you've got some indication of what you've done so far.

Comment: @EvilBeer Sorry about that. I have added in the code. Any ideas what might be the problem?